# No graba evento ics iCalendar

Tags: php

estoy generando un archivo **ICS** con **iCalendar**, el archivo se genera correctamente sin errores el mismo envio por correo desde PHP en el telefono celular al tratar de agregar dicho evento generado no se guarda en el calendario, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
require_once("../icalendar/zapcallib.php");
$file = '../invite.ics';

$organizer = 'xx.xx@email.com';
$title = $_POST['title'];
//obtengo fechas inicio/fin
$event_start = $_POST['fecha_inicial'];
$event_end = $_POST['fecha_final'];
//llamamos a la clase iCalc
$icalobj = new ZCiCal();
//crear nodo principal evento
$eventobj = new ZCiCalNode("VEVENT", $icalobj->curnode);
//nodo titulo
$eventobj->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("SUMMARY:" . $title));
//nodo fecha inicio
$eventobj->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("DTSTART;TZID=America/Guayaquil:" . ZCiCal::fromSqlDateTime($event_start)));
//nodo fecha final
$eventobj->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("DTEND;TZID=America/Guayaquil:" . ZCiCal::fromSqlDateTime($event_end)));


$uid = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . "@email.com";
$eventobj->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("UID:" . $uid));
// DTSTAMP fecha automatica requerida
$eventobj->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("DTSTAMP:" . ZCiCal::fromSqlDateTime()));
//LOCATION referencia
$eventobj->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("LOCATION:" . $_POST['direccion']));
//nodo organizador
$eventobj->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("ORGANIZER;CN=RGmanagementcorp:MAILTO:" . $organizer));
//nodo descripcion
$eventobj->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("Description:" . ZCiCal::formatContent(
    "Reunion RG"
)));
//obtengo el ics en variable como string
$ics_file_contents = $icalobj->export();
//coloco el ics string en archivo $file
file_put_contents($file, $ics_file_contents);
```

con dicho codigo me genera un archivo como este:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ZContent.net//ZapCalLib 1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Normas ISO
DTSTART;TZID=America/Guayaquil:20190507T093000
DTEND;TZID=America/Guayaquil:20190507T103000
UID:2019-05-06-18-55-35@email.com
DTSTAMP:20190506T235535
LOCATION:La Ronda
ORGANIZER;CN=RGmanagementcorp:MAILTO:xx.xx@email.com
Description:Reunion RG
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

de antemano gracias por sus sugerencias..!!